# JSON parsing with Gson returns null

Tags: android, gson

This is my `Fragment`:

```
public class PersonnelListFragment extends Fragment {
    public TextView test;
    private View root;

    public PersonnelListFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_personnel_list, container, false);

        Ion.with(getActivity()).load("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/e08f8a1b06319d109e0be8561d3948ce/raw/e459314b4bf8d45e82fec783b5435e6e82e6a1bc/p.json")
                .asJsonArray()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonArray result) {

                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<PersonClass>>() {}.getType();
                        List<PersonClass> gsonResponse = gson.fromJson(result, listType);

                        test = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.test_text_view);
                        test.setText(gsonResponse.toString()+"\n"+gsonResponse.get(0).firstName+"\n"+gsonResponse.get(0).getFirstName()+"\n"+result);
                    }
                });

        return root;
    }
}
```

this is PersonClass.java

```
public class PersonClass {
@SerializedName("\"firstName\"")
public String firstName;
@SerializedName("\"lastName\"")
public String lastName;
@SerializedName("\"age\"")
public int age;
@SerializedName("\"photo\"")
public String photo;
@SerializedName("\"address\"")
public String address;
@SerializedName("\"streetAddress\"")
public String streetAddress;
@SerializedName("\"city\"")
public String city;
@SerializedName("\"phoneNumber\"")
public String phoneNumber;

public void setFirstName(String firstName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getFirstName(){
    return firstName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName){
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getLastName(){
    return lastName;
}

public void setAge(int age){
    this.age = age;
}

public Integer getAge(){
    return age;
}

public void setPhoto(String photo){
    this.photo = photo;
}

public String getPhoto(){
    return photo;
}

public void setAddress(String address){
    this.address = address;
}

public String getAddress(){
    return address;
}

public void setStreetAddress(String streetAddress){
    this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
}

public String getStreetAddress(){
    return streetAddress;
}
public void setCity(String city){
    this.city = city;
}

public String getCity(){
    return city;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber){
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public String getPhoneNumber(){
    return phoneNumber;
}
}
```

You can see my JSON here.

```
[{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "age": 25,
    "photo": "http://images.mastermp3.net/artwork/nw/nw2560459789391eb5ad57c83786fa8156.jpg",
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
        "city": "New York"
    },
    "phoneNumber": "212 555-1234"
}, {
    "firstName": "Jane",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "age": 27,
    "photo": "http://socialventurepartners.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/www.socialventurepartners.org/sites/43/2013/08/Jane-Ragle.jpg",
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "17 3rd Street",
        "city": "Washington"
    },
    "phoneNumber": "646 555-4567"
}]
```

I investigated a lot of questions like mine but couldn't find a solution. People mostly said add `@SerializedName` to you object class when I added it gave me an error:

> Expected `String` but Found `Object`

Then I add `\"` to serializednames then it worked but now I can only get `null` when I call class object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address is a `JSONObject`, but you're trying to deserialize it into a `String`.

Something like this should work:

*Address* POJO:

```
public class Address {

    private String streetAddress;
    private String city;
}
```

*Person* POJO:

```
public class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    private String photo;
    private Address address;
    private String phoneNumber;
}
```

Deserializing:

```
List<Person> persons = new Gson()
    .fromJson(result, new TypeToken<List<Person>>(){}.getType());
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use extra quotation marks in @SerializedName? It most likely breaks your code. Also, you try to serialize 'address' object as a String, that will cause "Expected String but Found Object" error you had.

Solution: remove extra quotation marks and create new class:

**Address.java**

```
public class Address {
    public String streetAddress;
    public String city;
}
```

**PersonClass.java**

```
@SerializedName("address")
public Address address;
```

Then you can access address fields like this:

```
person.address.city;
person.address.streetAddress;
```

Answer (score 1):

remove `\` from your `SerializedName`

```
@SerializedName("\"firstName\"")
```

it should be like

```
@SerializedName("firstName")
```

Comment: When I do it, it gives an error that says expected string but found object.

Comment: @AliyasarErdogan look at my answer above, there is complete solution to this error